# How to access MySQL on Amazon RDS from an EC2 instance with rotating ip addresses?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I currently have a python script running on an EC2 linux instance. I'm rotating proxies in this instance with NordVPN. However, I must also be able to connect to an RDS Mysql database.

Because I'm constantly rotating proxies the script is unable to connect to the database as the new ip address is not a part of the VPC security group associated with the database. What should I do now ? Does the python script need to update the VPC security group every time it is using a new proxy ? Or is there a more elegant way of solving this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you dual-network and use the internal AWS network instead of the VPN to connect to the RDS?

Comment: Talking to RDS through the proxy does not sound like a good idea because at that point your RDS has to be public / internet facing. Just don't use the proxy for this EC2-RDS communication.

Comment: You need to disable "publicly accessible" on the RDS instance, and make sure you aren't routing your VPC's IP range through the VPN.

Comment: @ceejayoz I could do what I need to do with the proxy on, turn the proxy off, connect to the database and then turn the proxy on again. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: That depends on how you configure the proxy, you can have the proxy enabled but explicitly route some traffic not through the proxy. How do you currently use / setup the proxy?

Comment: @luk2302 That's exactly what I want to do and don't know yet how to. Basically the EC2 instance should communicate with the RDS bypassing the proxy. It is a routing issue. The proxy is simply configured to turn on and rotate every 100 requests. Any ideas ?

Comment: Once again: how do you currently setup the proxy, EC2 does not have a proxy builtin, does your python code have a proxy, does the OS have a proxy set, ...!?

Comment: @luk2302 I'm simply using NordVPN and a package called NordVPN-switcher. NordVPN is installed in the instance and NordVPN-switcher manages it, i.e. turns it on and rotates the proxies after a number of requests automatically.